# Foursquare API nearByVenue service changed

Tags: ios, foursquare

There was direct API calls to retrieve all list of `nearByVenues`:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues.json?geolat=40.562362&geolong=-111.938689&l=10
```

But now its no longer accessible.

I think Foursquare team has removed direct calls or may be changed something else.

I was able to access above URL long time back.

Please suggest how to retrieve venue details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foursquare discontinued the v1 api recently, you'll need to make a call to this endpoint instead:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.html

It should be pretty simple to port your code, here's is your query in the new structure:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.562362,-111.938689&limit=10
```

(you'll need to add your oauth credentials to the end for it to work though)